Power Apps Items Not In Collection
How do I find records in a table that are NOT in a collection?
Filter(Requirements, ID in RequirementsC.ID)

The above is records that are in the collection right?
I've tried
Filter(Requirements, Not(ID in RequirementsC.ID))


In something like ClearCollect(Requirements, { ID: 1, Name: "Req1" }, { ID: 2, Name: "Req2" }, { ID: 3, Name: "Req3" }, { ID: 4, Name: "Req4" }); ClearCollect(RequirementsD, { ID: 2, Name: "Req2" }, { ID: 3, Name: "Req3" }), the expression Filter(Requirements, Not(ID in RequirementsD.ID)) does return only the items not in the second collection (in this case, ID:1 and ID:4). Do you have any error in your expression, or is the result incorrect?

I get "Error when trying to retrieve data from the network: Not operator along with the Custom Named Condition operators is not allowed"

What is the type of 'Requirements'? From the error message it seems like a connected data source (such as a Dataverse table, a list in SharePoint, or something similar). This seems like a bug in the product, but there may be a way to work around it depending on the type of the data source.

Requirements is a dataverse table, RequirementsC is a collection taken from a filter of the Requirements table
ClearCollect(RequirementsC, Filter(Requirements, ID in lookupList));

This looks like a bug in the product: the expression is being delegated to the server, but the server cannot handle it.
One way to work around this issue is to force the expression to be executed on the client side, with something like the expression below:
Filter(FirstN(Requirements, 2000), Not(ID in RequirementsC.ID))

This expression is currently not delegated to Dataverse, so it will first try get the first 2000 items from the Requirements table (up to the data row limit). If your Requirements table has less than that limit, then this should work in your scenario.

That could be it, there's over 2000 items
